# Como receber os dados em JSON (REST)

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, rest, webhook

Olá, eu to aprendendo a programar, estou no 1 semestre de desenvolvimento e to sendo cobrado no trabalho pra aprender a fazer isso, e eu gostaria de saber se o que eu fiz ta certo ou não

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" dir="ltr">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Formulário de cadastro</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

<h1>Formulário de cadastro</h1>

<form name="form" id="form" class="cadastro" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validarForm();" required>

  <div class="grupoform">
    <label for= "Nome">Nome: </label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome completo..." required>
  </div>

  <div class="grupoform">
    <label for="Senha">Senha: </label>
    <input type="password" id="senha" placeholder="Digite sua senha" required>
  </div>

  <div class="grupoform">
    <label for="senhanovamente">Confirme sua senha: </label>
    <input type="password" id="senhanovamente" placeholder="Digite sua senha novamente" required>
  </div>

  <div class="grupoform">
    <label for="cpf">CPF: </label>
    <input type="text" id="cpf" required>
  </div>

  <div class="grupoform">
    <label for="email">E-mail: </label>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="jhon@emai l.com.br" required>
  </div>

  <div class="grupoform">
    <label for="cep">CEP: </label>
    <input type="text" id="cep" required>
  </div>

  <div class="grupoform">
    <label for="endereco">Endereço: </label>
    <input type="text" id="endereco" required>
  </div>

  <div class="grupoform">
    <label for="bairro">Bairro: </label>
    <input type="text" id="bairro" required>
  </div>

<div class="grupoform">
  <label for="complemento">Complemento: </label>
  <input type="text" id="complemento">
</div>

<div class="grupoform">
  <label for="cidade">Cidade: </label>
  <input type="text" id="cidade" required>
</div>

<div class="grupoform">
  <label for="estado">Estado: </label>
  <input type="text" id="estado" required>
</div>

<div class="grupoform">
  <label for="numero">Numero: </label>
  <input type="text" id="numero" required>
</div>


<div class="grupoform">
  <label for="telefone">Telefone: </label>
  <input type="text" id="telefone" placeholder=" DDD 999999999" required>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button type="button" name="button" id="enviar">Enviar</button>
  <button type="reset" name="button">Limpar</button>
</div>
<div id="respostas">

</div>
  </form>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/validacao.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/ajax.js"></script>



</html>
```

Agora a parte de js

```
$("#enviar").click(function(){

  var nome = $("#nome").val();
  var cpf = $("#cpf").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var rua = $("#endereco").val();
  var complemento = $("#complemento").val();
  var bairro = $("#bairro").val();
  var cep = $("#cep").val();
  var cidade = $("#cidade").val();
  var estado = $("#estado").val();
  var telefone = $("#telefone").val();
  var numero = $("#numero").val();
  var localidade =  {rua,complemento,bairro,cep,cidade,estado,numero};
  var investidor = {nome,cpf,email,localidade,telefone};


  $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.webhookinbox.com/i/LjzRS86F/in/",
    type: "POST",
    data: {"investidor":{"nome":nome, "cpf":cpf, "email":email, "localidade":{"rua":rua,"complemento":complemento,"bairro":bairro,"cep":cep,"cidade":cidade,"estado":estado,"numero":numero},"telefone":telefone}},
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data.serialize());
  },
  error: function(error){
       console.log("Something went wrong", error);
   }
  });
});
```

pfvr, eu to precisando muito de ajuda, e eu não tenho ideia de como resolver isso... os dados no webhook estão sendo enviados errado, era pra enviar em JSON

(desculpem pelo "leiguismo")

Comment: em `$.ajax({ ... });`, troque `contentType: "application/json"` para `dataType: "json"`

Comment: Mesmo erro......

Comment: Troque o `data: ...` por `data: JSON.stringify(...)`

Comment: nem enviou mais

Comment: que erro dá, no console?

Answer (score 0):

Usando `dataType: "json"` você precisa ter certeza que a resposta do servidor é no formato JSON, no caso do **webhookinbox** por padrão responde apenas com texto `OK`. Da forma que utilizou acima, o post irá dar erro, porém irá retornar `readyState: 4` e `status: 200`. Que significa sucesso, mas como o formato da resposta não está em JSON catch será um erro.

Observado as [Docs do Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>
> Type: String
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none
>   is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of
>   the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield
>   a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and
>   anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and
>   the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are:

...

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
>   object. Cross-domain "json" requests are converted to "jsonp" unless
>   the request includes jsonp: false in its request options. The JSON
>   data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and
>   a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also
>   rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead.
>   (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

Tente utilizar o código abaixo:

```
$("#enviar").click(function() {

    var nome = $("#nome").val();
    var cpf = $("#cpf").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var rua = $("#endereco").val();
    var complemento = $("#complemento").val();
    var bairro = $("#bairro").val();
    var cep = $("#cep").val();
    var cidade = $("#cidade").val();
    var estado = $("#estado").val();
    var telefone = $("#telefone").val();
    var numero = $("#numero").val();
    var localidade = {
        rua,
        complemento,
        bairro,
        cep,
        cidade,
        estado,
        numero
    };
    var investidor = {
        nome,
        cpf,
        email,
        localidade,
        telefone
    };

    var dataJSON = {
        "investidor": {
            "nome": nome,
            "cpf": cpf,
            "email": email,
            "localidade": {
                "rua": rua,
                "complemento": complemento,
                "bairro": bairro,
                "cep": cep,
                "cidade": cidade,
                "estado": estado,
                "numero": numero
            },
            "telefone": telefone
        }
    };


    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.webhookinbox.com/i/0HLzO6AL/in/",
        type: "POST",
        data: dataJSON,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("Something went wrong", error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: então, tem algum "webhookinbox" que recebe em JSON ?

Comment: Com esse código, deu a mesma coisa que eu tinha conseguido, só que mesmo assim, não vai em JSON

Comment: Ele vai em JSON sim, a resposta do server que não é em JSON. Tente utilizar e criar um serviço com: https://www.mockable.io/

Comment: Eu consegui pelo webhook, só preciso saber como tirar o %5b e %5d, e substituilos pelos couchetes